# Diagonal of inverse of a specific matrix sum

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

I have a specific, high-dimensional, matrix $A=(D + \sigma^2 C C^T)$, where $D$ is a diagonal, positive-definite matrix and C is a banded diagonal, Toeplitz and non-invertible matrix. I want to find a way to compute (or estimate with a relatively good accuracy) $Diag(A^{-1})$, namely the diagonal of its inverse, without computing the full inverse.

I already had several ideas, the thing is that $\sigma^2$  can be quite large and $D$ acts more like a regularizer on the (singular) inverse of $\sigma^2 C C^T$, so I can't perform a Taylor approximation around $D$. Also, using the Woodbury identity $A^{-1}= D^{-1} - D^{-1} C^T (\frac{1}{\sigma^2}I + CD^{-1}C^T)^{-1} C D^{-1}$, but I cannot find anything useful based on this expression.

I simply wants to know if anyone have an idea on how to compute this diagonal or if it is definitely hopeless.

Comment: The Woodbury identity looks like a promising way to go. Would it be possible to get a good $RQ$ decomposition of $C$?

Comment: I'm not sure about the RQ decomposition, I would say yes since I saw a few papers proposing fast methods for the RQ decomposition of toeplitz matrices (however I have access to the eigenvalue decomposition). I can see why it would simplify the inversion, and that's a very good lead, thank you :)